# Prestashop Men/Women Switch

Tags: prestashop

Just a small question

I'd like to add a switch button on the top of the website that allow users to change of GENDER

For exemple:

I have an architecture like so :

```
CAT1
 SUBCAT1
  MEN
   ARTICLE1
   ARTICLE2
   ARTICLE3
  WOMEN
   ARTICLE1
   ARTICLE2
   ARTICLE3
SUBCAT2
```

etc...

How could I achieve this ?
Or do you think I should do another way ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you already have structured your categories according to gender, you can just have your "switch" be a link to the other gender's category.

Comment: Thanks ! But Is there a way to reload the page with an argument retriving the gender ? And is this a good way to manage my categories or should I manage the Men / Women with an argument in each articles ?

Answer (score 0):

Are the articles basically the same for each gender? Or are they completely different? Most webshops I visit, the articles for men and women are mostly different, and the selection is usually done in the regular categories menu. But if the articles are the same, only with slightly different attributes, I guess your idea makes sense. The easiest and least intrusive in the latter case is to create your products with attributes `men` and `women`, which will give you a dropdown with gender selection for the products. If you need something more complex than that, the easiest is probably to edit the theme template for the page(s) you want the switch on. The "page argument" would simply be a link to the corresponding other gender category.

Comment: Cool thanks :) NilsH I will try to make the products filtered by arguments with a button on the top of the page and reload the content by AJAX with the related argument. I will try that tomorrow :) thanks again for the answer. best regards!

Comment: OK I think I've got the trick. SHOP -> CAT1 ->MODEL 1  and  SHOP -> CAT1 ->MODEL 2 and I've created two other ctaegories MEN / WOMAN and linked every product to them seperatly. I see now every product by gender. But How do I associate Two categorie that are on the same level ? I'd like to see the structure of CAT1 in MEN you see :(